# Group by array of objects by a nested key

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, group-by

I have the following data:

```
const data = [
    {
        parent: {
            id: "1",
            name: "Europe"
        },
        item: {
            name: "Italy"
        },
        score: 5
    },
    {
        parent: {
            id: "1",
            name: "Europe"
        },
        item: {
            name: "France"
        },
        score: 4.5
    },
    {
        parent: {
            id: "1",
            name: "Europe"
        },
        item: {
            name: "UK"
        },
        score: 4.9
    },
    {
        parent: {
            id: "2",
            name: "Afrique"
        },
        item: {
            name: "Morocco"
        },
        score: 3.1
    },
    {
        parent: {
            id: "2",
            name: "Afrique"
        },
        item: {
            name: "Egypt"
        },
        score: 3.9
    }
];
```

I want to group it based on the `parent.id` and calculate the average score, so I can have the following result:

```
[
    {
        parent: {
            id: "1",
            name: "Europe",
            items: [
                {
                    name: "Italy"
                },
                {
                    name: "France"
                },
                {
                    name: "UK"
                }
            ],
            score: 4.8
        }
    },
    {
        parent: {
            id: "2",
            name: "Afrique",
            items: [
                {
                    name: "Morocco"
                },
                {
                    name: "Egypt"
                }
            ],
            score: 3.5
        }
    }
]
```

I used the following function, but it doesn't work for the nested key, and also it's doesn't return the desired result schema.

```
let group = cars.reduce((r, a) => {
   console.log("a", a);
   console.log('r', r);
   r[a.make] = [...r[a.parent.id] || [], a];
   return r;
}, {});
console.log("group", group);
```

Comment: What is `a.make`? There's no `make` property in your objects.

Comment: It should be `a.parent.id`.

Comment: Shouldn't the resulting array, have the scores inside each item, not as an attribute of the parent?

Comment: @GrandPhuba yea, actually that's better, I'll update the question. THANKS

Answer (score 1):

You can use `_reduce()` function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

```
var result = data.reduce((res, data) => {
  if(!res[data.parent.id]) {
    data.item = [data.item];
    res[data.parent.id] = data;
  } else {
    res[data.parent.id]['item'].push(data['item']);
    res[data.parent.id]['score'] = (res[data.parent.id]['score'] + data['score'])/2;
  }
  return res;
}, [])
.filter(x => x != null)
```

```js
const data = [
    {
        parent: {
            id: "1",
            name: "Europe"
        },
        item: {
            name: "Italy"
        },
        score: 5
    },
    {
        parent: {
            id: "1",
            name: "Europe"
        },
        item: {
            name: "France"
        },
        score: 4.5
    },
    {
        parent: {
            id: "1",
            name: "Europe"
        },
        item: {
            name: "UK"
        },
        score: 4.9
    },
    {
        parent: {
            id: "2",
            name: "Afrique"
        },
        item: {
            name: "Morocco"
        },
        score: 3.1
    },
    {
        parent: {
            id: "2",
            name: "Afrique"
        },
        item: {
            name: "Egypt"
        },
        score: 3.9
    }
];

var result = data.reduce((res, data) => {
  if(!res[data.parent.id]) {
    data.item = [data.item];
    res[data.parent.id] = data;
  } else {
res[data.parent.id]['item'].push(data['item']);
res[data.parent.id]['score'] = (res[data.parent.id]['score'] + data['score'])/2;
  }
  return res;
}, [])
.filter(x => x != null)

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an object/hashmap, then format the resulting object into an array.

```
let continents = {}
data.forEach(function(country){
    const continent_id = country.parent.id
    let continent = continents[continent_id]
    if(!continent){
        continent = {
             id: continent_id,
             name: country.parent.name,
             items: [],
        }
        continents[continent_id] = continent
    }
    continent.items.push({
       name: country.item.name,
       score: country.score
    })

})
continents = Object.entries(continents).map(item => ({parent: item[1]}))
console.log(continents)
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        "parent":{
            "id":"1",
            "name":"Europe",
            "items":[
                {
                    "name":"Italy",
                    "score":5
                },
                {
                    "name":"France",
                    "score":4.5
                },
                {
                    "name":"UK",
                    "score":4.9
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "parent":{
            "id":"2",
            "name":"Afrique",
            "items":[
                {
                    "name":"Morocco",
                    "score":3.1
                },
                {
                    "name":"Egypt",
                    "score":3.9
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: Note, I put the score inside each item as mentioned in the comments of your question

Answer (score 0):

From the data you've provided if you additionaly need to count average of `score` property, use the following reduce method: it will iterate trough your data, group it and calculate total score value and count of score values. And after reduce groups object perform map that will calculate average for score for all the groups using `totalScore` and `scoreCount`

```js
const data = [
    {
        parent: {
            id: "1",
            name: "Europe"
        },
        item: {
            name: "Italy"
        },
        score: 5
    },
    {
        parent: {
            id: "1",
            name: "Europe"
        },
        item: {
            name: "France"
        },
        score: 4.5
    },
    {
        parent: {
            id: "1",
            name: "Europe"
        },
        item: {
            name: "UK"
        },
        score: 4.9
    },
    {
        parent: {
            id: "2",
            name: "Afrique"
        },
        item: {
            name: "Morocco"
        },
        score: 3.1
    },
    {
        parent: {
            id: "2",
            name: "Afrique"
        },
        item: {
            name: "Egypt"
        },
        score: 3.9
    }
];

let group = data.reduce((acc, rec) => {
   if (acc.find(item => item.parent.id === rec.parent.id))
     {
       const idx = acc.findIndex(item => item.parent.id === rec.parent.id)
       acc[idx].parent.items = acc[idx].parent.items.concat(rec.item)
       acc[idx].parent.score += rec.score
       acc[idx].parent.scoreCount +=1
       
     } else {
       acc = acc.concat({parent: {...rec.parent, score: rec.score, items: [rec.item], scoreCount:1}})
       
     }
   
   return acc
}, []).map(it => ({parent: {id: it.parent.id, name:it.parent.name, score: (it.parent.score / it.parent.scoreCount), items: it.parent.items}}));

console.log("group", group);
```